# Conditional percentages calculations - R

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, criteria, percentage

I have this `df`:

```
> day <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
> Salesperson<- c("Chris", "Phil", "Joy", "Jess", "Chris", "Phil", "Joy", "Jess", "Chris", "Phil", "Joy", "Jess")
> Sales<-c(32,54,65,43,87,54,21,65,75,75,47,56)
> df <- cbind(day, Salesperson,Sales)
> df
      day Salesperson Sales
 [1,] "1" "Chris"     "32" 
 [2,] "1" "Phil"      "54" 
 [3,] "1" "Joy"       "65" 
 [4,] "1" "Jess"      "43" 
 [5,] "2" "Chris"     "87" 
 [6,] "2" "Phil"      "54" 
 [7,] "2" "Joy"       "21" 
 [8,] "2" "Jess"      "65" 
 [9,] "3" "Chris"     "75" 
[10,] "3" "Phil"      "75" 
[11,] "3" "Joy"       "47" 
[12,] "3" "Jess"      "56"
```

I need to compute the percentage of sales per day for each salesperson. I have been trying with `dpply` or adding a new column with those values, but none of them works. An example:

For day 1, Chris, and `sales = 32`, the percentage should be `32/(32+54+65+43)`

Comment: Maybe use something like the slice function: `df %>% group_by(day, Salesperson) %>% slice(C/which.sum(C))`....not sure if this is right but probably along these lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the group_by() and ungroup() multiple times. You can just do this using tidyverse:

```
day <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Salesperson<- c("Chris", "Phil", "Joy", "Jess", "Chris", "Phil", "Joy", "Jess", "Chris", "Phil", "Joy", "Jess")
Sales<-c(32,54,65,43,87,54,21,65,75,75,47,56)
df <- cbind(day, Salesperson,Sales)

df <- as.data.frame(df)

df$Sales <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Sales))


df %<>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  mutate(perc = Sales / sum(Sales))

> df
A tibble: 12 x 4
Groups:   day [3]
   day   Salesperson Sales   perc
   <fct> <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1     Chris         32. 0.165 
 2 1     Phil          54. 0.278 
 3 1     Joy           65. 0.335 
 4 1     Jess          43. 0.222 
 5 2     Chris         87. 0.383 
 6 2     Phil          54. 0.238 
 7 2     Joy           21. 0.0925
 8 2     Jess          65. 0.286 
 9 3     Chris         75. 0.296 
10 3     Phil          75. 0.296 
11 3     Joy           47. 0.186 
12 3     Jess          56. 0.221
```

PROOF:

```
df$perc[1]  == 32/(32+54+65+43)
```

gives

```
 [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my code. I copied and pasted exactly your code, and still gives me the percentage by the whole column (not by group). How can I know if group_by in my code is working properly? I didn't unpacked tidyverse as I already unpacked (and I'm using) dlpyr, but it's the same as I know. So, what can be the error I'm having?

Comment: Is there any chance you loaded the "plyr" package as well after loading dplyr? That might cause this problem. You could restart R or detach plyr using this code: detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE). Hope this works now!

Comment: Still not working. I have unpacked everything and just loaded dplyr package, and also load as I did and after detaching as you tell me, and it gives me this error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column perc must be length 4 (the group size) or one, not 12`. To use mutate I need to load plyr package. But if I load it, doesn't work too. What can be the problem here?

Comment: You don't have to load plyr to use mutate. Mutate is a dplyr function as well. Really, just detach plyr or restart R. You only need dplyr. I used the %<>% to run and update df instantly, which is from magrittr or tidyverse. Change this to %>% and you only need dplyr.

Comment: I don't get it. If I just load magrittr and dplyr, it gives me the same error I showed above. If then I load plyr package, the code run, but gives the wrong values in percentages. PS: Should I create a new question for this new problem?